# Value too large for field not stored

Tags: solr

I have a Solr schema with this field

```
<field docValues="true" indexed="false" multiValued="false" name="big_field" stored="false" type="StrField"/>
```

When I try to index a document with a large value for the field `big_field`, I have this error :

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id
>   1528882422008 to the index; possible analysis error: DocValuesField
>   "big_field" is too large, must be <= 32766

Can you explain me why ? What should I do to fix this ? Switch to a  `TextField` ?

Answer (score 2):

**StrField limit is 32,766 bytes.**

> String (UTF-8 encoded string or Unicode). Strings are intended for
>   small fields and are not tokenized or analyzed in any way. They have a
>   hard limit of slightly less than 32K.

To store more than 32 32,766 bytes you can use TextField as a single token.

```
<fieldtype name="string_big" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

**Keyword Tokenizer** - this tokenizer treats the entire text field as a single token.

Comment: I have the same error when trying to index a string with 300k char in this field with your type.